# Words for the performance that I see first time

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the word that stands for the thing that I see first time in my life.

Here is the sample sentence:
His show was the first show that I visited and watched under the stage.

(There may be some grammatical mistake since I am English learner.)

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you looking for: *His show was the **first show I'd ever seen***?

Comment: You see a show or you attend a show.  (You watched it from *under* the stage?!?)

Comment: @Jim No, I am looking for: First show that I saw in my life

Comment: The first show I'd ever seen ***IS*** the first show that I saw in my life.

Comment: @Jim Then, can I say like this: I went to watch my first time rock concert.

Comment: I went to see my first rock concert [ever].

Comment: Adding ***ever*** at the end reinforces that this is the first in your whole life. Otherwise people tend to say things like, 'I went to see my first rock concert in 10 years'  which means that they'd seen them before but the last one they'd seen was at least 10 years ago.

Comment: @Jim Oh, I can clearly understand now! Thank you again !!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was **a first-time spectator** when I went to see "The Phantom Of The Opera" at Her Majesty's Theatre.

> - [**spectator**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spectator) - (noun) - a person who watches an event, show, game, activity, etc., often as part of an audience

Answer (score 0):

"It was my inaugural experience seeing the Grateful Dead. What's more, I had backstage passes for my best friend, Ricky, and me. From behind the stage, it was fun, but it wasn't until we hit the dance floor that the show became truly epic."